# R - Merging csvs with similar data to show if row names are present in respective files

Tags: r

Having a difficult time describing this which is probably why I'm not certain what function/what I'm looking for. Would appreciate someone describing what this function is called.

Basically, I have about a dozen .csv files, each with lists of a few hundred genes each. None of the lists includes all gene names.

What I'm looking to do, is to merge all those lists together and get a comprehensive list of all genes with an indication of which files said genes show up in. I don't need the values, just 1s and 0s to indicate if those names show up in said file is plenty.

I can already tell this may not make sense, so this analogy may help:

Let's say I have three files, *Fruit A*, *Fruit B*, and *Fruit C*. *Fruit A* has 2 apples, 3 bananas, and 1 orange. *Fruit B* has 1 apple and 1 coconut. *Fruit C* has 2 oranges and a lime. I want to merge it and produce a file that looks like this:

| FRUIT NAME | Fruit A | Fruit B | Fruit C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Banana | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Orange | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Coconut | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Lime | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first convert all three files (.csv) into individual vectors, as you have stated that these are lists only.
- then take unique elements out of these lists.
- use `%in%` operator to generate your individual file columns

```
fruitA <- c('apple', 'banana', 'orange')
fruitB <- c('apple', 'coconut')
fruitC <- c('orange', 'lime')

data.frame(fruitname = unique(c(fruitA, fruitB, fruitC))) %>%
  mutate(colA = as.numeric(fruitname %in% fruitA), 
         colB = as.numeric(fruitname %in% fruitB),
         colC = as.numeric(fruitname %in% fruitC))

  fruitname colA colB colC
1     apple    1    1    0
2    banana    1    0    0
3    orange    1    0    1
4   coconut    0    1    0
5      lime    0    0    1
```

You may also make of `purrr::reduce2` if you have many items

```
reduce2(list(fruitA, fruitB, fruitC), 
        list("fruitA", "fruitB", "fruitC"),
        .init = data.frame(fruitname = unique(c(fruitA, fruitB, fruitC))),
       ~ ..1 %>% mutate(!!..3 := +(fruitname %in% ..2)))

  fruitname fruitA fruitB fruitC
1     apple      1      1      0
2    banana      1      0      0
3    orange      1      0      1
4   coconut      0      1      0
5      lime      0      0      1
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Oh excellent. That reduce2 will be very helpful. I'm going to keep expanding sets and will probably have hundreds. Was dreading doing it manually.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  Please accept the answer, for future reference, as per usual guidelines on SO. :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The first solution using mutate worked perfectly for 3 dataframes. Unfortunately, when I expanded it to 7 sets, it resulted in this error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 77, 107, 197, 53, 1326, 3764
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: To above. Figured out the problem. Issue was I didn't reduce my objects to data frames first. Was trying to pull them straight in from CSV.